# Permissions on different pages

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 4 different pages and 4 different groups of users. I want to give permission to each group to view only its own page.
Is there a way to assigne specific permissions to a specific page, i know that it works for list and libraries, but does it for pages?

Comment: you can do that using item level permisisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to your page library
- Select the file
  [image]
- Select Shared With option
- On the permissions popup box, click on ADVANCED
  [image]
- click on stop inheriting permissions

[image]
 - Then you can manage the permissions for to that item/page